# Actions on Google - set Activity Controls

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I've got an Actions on Google application which runs when shared with another Google account but doesn't run for the application owner.
I keeps asking me to:
**Please turn on Voice & Audio Activity**, Web & App Activity, and Device Information permissions for your Google Account.

Voice, Audio, Web & App activity are turned on for my account. Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Is the activity settings enabled for the account that is associated with the device that you are using for testing?

Answer (score 3):

You also need to do the following

Check the check box next to “Include Chrome browsing history and activity from websites and apps that use Google services.”

[image]

See the google documentation bellow.

https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7382500